# Comparing Datetime and unorderable types

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to compare datetimes from different sources (therefore the formats are slightly different). Essentially I'm checking if it's past sunset to dim a display panel by looking up the current values in a dictionary that's updated daily.

I've figured out how to get the ISO format down to just the time element (`_ss` below) but struggling to actually get the `Datetime.datetime` value (`_herenow` below) correct:

The formats:

```
_ss       05:50:06
_herenow  08:35:21.992656
```

My code:

```
def is_day_time():
    _now = datetime.datetime.now()
    _ss = local_weather.get('mylocal_ss')
    _sr = local_weather.get('mylocal_sr')
    _ss = _ss.time()
    _sr = _sr.time()
    _herenow = _now.time()
    if _herenow >= _ss or _now <= _sr:
        _isnight = 1
        mymatrix.DisplayBright(_isnight)
    else:
        _isnight = 0
        mymatrix.DisplayBright(_isnight)
```

The error I'm getting:

```
if _herenow >= _ss or _now <= _sr:
TypeError: unorderable types: datetime.datetime() <= datetime.time()
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use only `_herenow`, since it's a `time`.

Also, you can simplify the conditional:

```
_isnight = (_herenow <= _sr or _herenow >= _ss)
mymatrix.DisplayBright(_isnight)
```

As an aside: it is not wrong to prefix your variable names with underscores, but it is strange.

Comment: To my knowledge, prefixing variables with underscores means that you don't want them touched

Comment: @alec_a Since they're in a function, it's unclear who would touch them or how anyway…

Comment: @alec_a Yup, in class scope. However, this is function scope, so those variables can't be touched anyway.

Comment: No, wrong, I mistook the `or` operator for `and`. It's not equivalent after all.

Comment: @deceze I think this is better, overall.

Comment: @gmds Thanks - The _prefix was me trying to troubleshoot the code so I could keep track of the changing variables. Thanks for the simplified conditional all working.